# Failed to set session cookie Maybe you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: php, nginx, phpmyadmin, php7, cookie

I configure my phpadmin with nginx and I have a problem to login. my phpadmin version 4.9.5 my php version PHP 7.4.3 .

it work when I try  to change `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']` in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` with `'http'` or `'config'`

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
```

but with cookie  `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';` not working and return `Failed`

to set session cookie Maybe you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS .I search I

found clear browser ...but it is not a solution